# Applying operation to unevenly split portions of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have three 1D numpy arrays:

1. A list of times at which some measurements occurred (`t`).
2. A list of measurements that occurred at each of the times in `t` (`y`).
3. A (shorter) list of times for some some external changes that affected these measurements (`b`).

Here is an example:

```
t = np.array([0.33856697,   1.69615293,   1.70257872,   2.32510279,
              2.37788203,   2.45102176,   2.87518307,   3.60941650,
              3.78275907,   4.37970516,   4.56480259,   5.33306546,
              6.00867792,   7.40217571,   7.46716989,   7.6791613 ,
              7.96938078,   8.41620336,   9.17116349,  10.87530965])
y = np.array([ 3.70209916,  6.31148802,  2.96578172,  3.90036915, 5.11728629,
               2.85788050,  4.50077811,  4.05113322,  3.55551093, 7.58624384,
               5.47249362,  5.00286872,  6.26664832,  7.08640263, 5.28350628,
               7.71646500,  3.75513591,  5.72849991,  5.60717179, 3.99436659])

b = np.array([ 1.7,  3.9,  9.5])
```

The elements of `b` fall between the bold and italicized elements `t`, breaking it into four uneven sized segments of lengths 2, 7, 10, 1.

I would like to apply an operation to each segment of `y` to get an array of size `b.size + 1`. Specifically, I want to know if *more* than half of the values of `y` within each segment fall above or below a certain bias.

I am currently using a for loop and slicing to apply my test:

```
bias = 5
categories = np.digitize(t, b)
result = np.empty(b.size + 1, dtype=np.bool_)
for i in range(result.size):
    mask = (categories == i)
    result[i] = (np.count_nonzero(y[mask] > bias) / np.count_nonzero(mask)) > 0.5
```

This seems extremely inefficient. Unfortunately, `np.where` won't help much in this situation. Is there a way to vectorize the operation I describe here to avoid the Python `for` loop?

---

By the way, here is a plot of `y` vs `t`, `bias`, and the regions delimited by `b` to show why the expected `result` is `array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)`:

[image]

Generated by

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
plt.ion()
f, a = plt.subplots()
a.plot(t, y, label='y vs t')
a.hlines(5, *a.get_xlim(), label='bias')
plt.tight_layout()
a.set_xlim(0, 11)
c = np.concatenate([[0], b, [11]])
for i in range(len(c) - 1):
    a.add_patch(Rectangle((c[i], 2.5), c[i+1] - c[i], 8 - 2.5, alpha=0.2, color=('red' if i % 2 else 'green'), zorder=-i-5))
a.legend()
```

Comment: Since your categories are contiguous can't you just use `add.reduceat` on the boolean you get by comparing with bias? Using the split points which you can probably get cheapest using `searchsorted`? Also if I'm not totally mistaken you can use the `diff` of the splitpoints as your denominator

Comment: @PaulPanzer. Could you please clarify that with a full answer. I am only getting a sense of where you are aiming here but I honestly have no idea what you mean in terms of a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this produce the same result?

```
split_points = np.searchsorted(t, np.r_[t[0], b, t[-1]])
numerator = np.add.reduceat(y > bias, split_points[:-1])
denominator = np.diff(split_points)
result = (numerator / denominator) > 0.5
```

Few notes: This approach relies on t being sorted. Then the bins relative to b will all be neat blocks, so we need no mask to describe them but just the endpoints in form of indices into t. That's what `searchsorted` finds for us.

Since your criterion doesn't appear to depend on group, we can make one big mask for all y in one go. Counting nonzeros in a boolean array is the same as summing, because the True's will be coerced to ones etc. The advantage in this case is that we can use `add.reduceat` which takes the array, a list of split points and then sums the blocks between the splits, which is precisely what we want.

To normalise we need to count the total number in each bin, but because the bins are contiguous we just need the difference of the split_points delineating that bin, which is where we use `diff`.

Comment: Any reason for `r_` vs `concatenate`?

Comment: Also, this is very well seen. I am impressed. And thank you.

Comment: Also, I was completely unaware of `reduceat`. It literally does exactly what I need.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `r_` is just a personal preference. -- Yes `reduceat` is extremely useful.  -- And you are welcome.  -- Just one question: does it actually work? Because I didn't test it.

Comment: Yep, works just fine. I checked that each step does what I want and it does.

Comment: Actually, there is an advantage in using `r_`. `concatenate` does not allow scalars in the sequence.

Comment: You've implicitly answered my next question too by the way, since I wanted a way to handle exact matches between `x` and `b` by including the `y` value in both regions. Luckily, reduceat can sort-of handle that with some very minimal additional filtering.

Comment: Interesting, What do you do? Copy the split point and reduce the copy by one? And then discard the sum corresponding to k, k-1 which is a nonsense value anyway?

Comment: Basically yes. `mask = t[ind[1:-1]] == b`, with `ind` being the `r_` expression. Duplicate split points at mask locations, expand mask accordingly, remove the duplicated ranges after the reduction.

Comment: I haven't checked if I need to switch to `np.digitize` to get that to work.