# Summarize ndarray by 2d array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I want to summarize a 3d array `dat` using indices contained in a 2d array `idx`.

Consider the example below. For each margin along `dat[:, :, i]`, I want to compute the median according to some index `idx`. The desired output (`out`) is a 2d array, whose rows record the index and columns record the margin. The following code works but is not very efficient. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
dat = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)
idx = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 2]])

out = np.empty((3, 3))
for i in np.unique(idx):
    out[i,] = np.median(dat[idx==i], axis = 0)
print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 1.5  2.5  3.5]
 [ 6.   7.   8. ]
 [ 9.  10.  11. ]]
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now. Not sure why you'd want to, but I have a vectorized solution in mind. Will update momentarily.

Comment: I've posted an answer that does not contain any explicit loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To visualize the problem better, I will refer to the 2x2 dimensions of the array as the rows and columns, and the 3 dimension as depth. I will refer to vectors along the 3rd dimension as "pixels" (pixels have length 3), and planes along the first two dimensions as "channels".

Your loop is accumulating a set of pixels selected by the mask `idx == i`, and taking the median of each channel within that set. The result is an Nx3 array, where N is the number of distinct incides that you have.

One day, [generalized ufuncs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.generalized-ufuncs.html) will be ubiquitous in numpy, and [`np.median`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) will be such a function. On that day, you will be able to use [`reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) magic<sup>1</sup> to do something like

```
unq, ind = np.unique(idx, return_inverse=True)
np.median.reduceat(dat.reshape(-1, dat.shape[-1]), np.r_[0, np.where(np.diff(unq[ind]))[0]+1])
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> See [Applying operation to unevenly split portions of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42447497/2988730) for more info on the specific type of magic.</sub>

Since this is not currently possible, you can use [`scipy.ndimage.median`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.median.html) instead. This version allows you to compute medians over a set of labeled areas in an array, which is exactly what you have with `idx`. This method assumes that your index array contains N densely packed values, all of which are in `range(N)`. Otherwise the reshaping operations will not work properly.

If that is not the case, start by transforming `idx`:

```
_, ind = np.unique(idx, return_inverse=True)
idx = ind.reshape(idx.shape)
```

OR

```
idx = np.unique(idx, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(idx.shape)
```

Since you are actually computing a separate median for each region and channel, you will need to have a set of labels for each channel. Flesh out `idx` to have a distinct set of indices for each channel:

```
chan = dat.shape[-1]
offset = idx.max() + 1
index = np.stack([idx + i * offset for i in range(chan)], axis=-1)
```

Now `index` has an identical set of regions defined in each channel, which you can use in `scipy.ndimage.median`:

```
out = scipy.ndimage.median(dat, index, index=range(offset * chan)).reshape(chan, offset).T
```

The input labels must be densely packed from zero to `offset * chan` for `index=range(offset * chan)` to work properly, and the `reshape` operation to have the right number of elements. The final transpose is just an artifact of how the labels are arranged.

Here is the complete product, along with an [IDEOne demo](https://ideone.com/w5FOps) of the result:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import median

dat = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)
idx = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 2]])

def summarize(dat, idx):
    idx = np.unique(idx, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(idx.shape)
    chan = dat.shape[-1]
    offset = idx.max() + 1
    index = np.stack([idx + i * offset for i in range(chan)], axis=-1)
    return median(dat, index, index=range(offset * chan)).reshape(chan, offset).T

print(summarize(dat, idx))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer! It's very efficient and works like a charm :) You're right, in my application observations are pixels and `idx` record the superpixels index.  The code is used to compute the median RGB values at the superpixel level.